# HTML5 checkValidity and Invisible Fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a simple form as below:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Line 1: <asp:TextBox ID="Line1TextBox" runat="server" placeholder="e.g. Street 9" required ></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        Fill Line 2? <asp:CheckBox ID="Line2CheckBox" runat="server" OnClick="Line2CheckBox_Chekced();"  />
        <br />
        <div ID="Line2Panel" style="display: none;">
            Line 2: <asp:TextBox ID="Line2TextBox" runat="server" placeholder="e.g. Street 9" required ></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="NextButton" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClientClick="return NextButton_Click();" />        
    </div>
</form>
```

The `Line2CheckBox` is toggling the `Line2Panel` with the following script:

```
function Line2CheckBox_Chekced() {
     $("#Line2Panel").toggle();
}
```

In the `NextButton_Click` I am checking whether the form is valid or not as follows:

```
function NextButton_Click() {
    if ($('#form1')[0].checkValidity()) {
        alert("from is valid");
   } else {
        alert("from is NOT valid");
   }
}
```

I have noticed the following:

- If I enter some value in the `Line1TextBox` and attempt to submit the form, while `Line2TextBox` is hidden, the form is not submitted because the form in not valid (`checkValidity()` returns false).
- If I click on the `CheckBox` to show `Line2TextBox` and enter some value in it, the form is submitted correctly.
- If I mark `Line2TextBox` as disabled and don't put any value, the form is submitted.

**My questions are:**

1. Is this the default behavior of HTML5 forms (invisible hidden fields but not disabled fields)?
2. More importantly, how to stop HTML5 from validating invisible fields (I have tried to use `oninvalid` event to check wehther the field is visible or not, `$(obj).is(":visible")`, then cancel the event but it didn't work)?

My goal is that if the field is invisble then mark it as valid, something like the following but I don't know where to write it (or to which event I should attach this code):

```
if (obj.willValidate && !$(obj).is(":visible")) 
    //cancel the validation event or consider the field as valid
```

Comment: A field that is not displayed on your screen is not of hidden type, it is just not shown, so it's perfectly normal it is validated as well. If you need custom validation, you should put it in place yourself. regarding disabled fields, I don't even think their value is even submitted, so that's perfectly logic once again that the'yre not validated... but once again you could force it with custom validation.

Comment: Can you please explain more about custom validation, I want something like if (obj.willValidate && !$(obj).is(":visible")) //cancel the validation event or consider the field as valid

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect that I mean invisible fields not hidden fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these could be logical answers to my questions:

1. It mekes sense to validate invisible fields. For example if a field is invisible because it is in an accordion control or in a collapsible panel, it should be validated.
2. One way to stop HTML5 from validating invisible fields is to mark them as not required. In my case when I check / uncheck the CheckBox I do the following:

   ```
   function Line2CheckBox_Chekced() {
       var isChecked = $("#Line2CheckBox").is(":checked");
       if (isChecked) {
            $("#Line2Panel").show();
            $("#Line2TextBox").attr("required", "");
       } else {
            $("#Line2Panel").hide();
            $("#Line2TextBox").removeAttr("required");
       }
   }
   ```

So I think I will be checking the following now:

1. How to cancel the validation of a certain control?
2. How to show the error message from invisible fields?

Comment: The answer is late, but adding/removing required attribute isn't suitable, because a) there are other possible HTML5 constraints and b) you don't want to keep track of all those elements inside of a form group. The best way is to you the disabled property on the element itself or better on the fieldset element: http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/K8EPm/

Answer (score 1):

Adding Alexander Farkas's comment as an answer because it helped me (emphasis mine):

> Adding/removing required attribute isn't always suitable because:
>
> a) There are other possible HTML5 constraints.
>
> b) You don't want to keep track of all those elements inside of a form group.
>
> **The best way is to add the disabled property on the element itself or on the fieldset element**

Example:

```
<fieldset disabled>
  <input type="text" name="foo" required />
</fieldset>
```